# Helper method accessing Display(Name) from given model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a little collection of helper methods that really help me buid some of the views i need to. All of them really simple and effective (although probably not implemented on the very best way possible). I'm having trouble on implementing just this one method ("RenderTitleCell"), that should render a html segment using a DisplayName from one of the view model's property, just like this one:

```
 <th>text obtained from DisplayName annotation of a model property</th>
```

The problem is that I really don't know how to pass the "text obtained from DisplayName annotation of a model property" since (as it states) it is obtained from the model class' display(name) annotation for a property.
Html.DisplayNameFor does a similar thing receiving a linq expression, but i really don't know how to implement this kind of stuff on my helper method.

So far, my method just receives the string to output on the < th >, but this really don't help much, since I don't know how to obtain the DisplayName of a propoerty from the view and in that case i have to use a string detached from the annotation on the class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could retrieve it from the metadata of the property.

Example:

```
public static IHtmlString MyHelperFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    string name = metadata.DisplayName;

    return new HtmlString(string.Format("<th>{0}</th>", html.Encode(name)));
}
```

and then:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.MyHelperFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Assuming that `SomeProperty` on your view model is decorated with the `[Display]` or `[DisplayName]` attributes:

```
[DisplayName("foo bar")]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

or:

```
[Display(Name = "foo bar")]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

the custom helper will generate:

```
<th>foo bar</th>
```

Comment: Guess that big part of my problem is using a cshtml file on the App_Code folder, with the @helper methods sintax. This really narrows my possibilities. Anyway, your suggestion seems perfect... Will implement a regular helper class and get rid of this format that i'm currently using. Tks a lot.